# How do I see the texture I've applied to my UV Unwrapped model?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

[image]

I've unwrapped the model and am ready to paint it, but I just can't get the reference grid to show on the viewport. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to go into [`Shader Editor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/shader_editor.html) and add the [`Image Texture`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/image.html) node & plug it into the *Principled BSDF* shader node. Press <kbd>F3</kbd> in the *Shader Editor* and search for *Image Texture* and add/plug it and then select your image within the Image Texture node.

[image]